# Android Unable to merge dex error. See content

Tags: android, gradle, android-build

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

I am using version 3.0.1 of Android Studio.

I also tried 'clean project' and 'rebuild project'.

*project build gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

*module build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
ext {
    grpcVersion = '1.4.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.backkom.speechtest"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled  true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
       artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.3.0'
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0"
        }
        grpc {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.plugins {
                javalite {}
                grpc {
                // Options added to --grpc_out
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    // gRPC
    compile "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:$grpcVersion"
    compile "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:$grpcVersion"
    compile "io.grpc:grpc-stub:$grpcVersion"
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.3.1'

    compile group: 'com.google.api.grpc', name: 'grpc-google-cloud-speech-v1', version: '0.1.13'

    // OAuth2 for Google API
    compile('com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.7.0') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
}
```

When I do a rebuild project, I get an error like below.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>   java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\backkom\AndroidStudioProjects\SpeechTest\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\backkom.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.protobuf\protobuf-java\3.3.1\e8964a2667e55d11a4505b329a4c34247663920b\protobuf-java-3.3.1.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [protobuf-java-3.3.1.jar:com/google/protobuf/ExperimentalApi.class]))

Answer (score 1):

Check if you (directly or transitively) assemble the APK with both `com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java` and `com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite`. The latter includes a subset of classes from the former and the dexer complains when it finds the first of the duplicated classes. You should exclude one of the two.

1. Exclude `protobuf-java` if you want to be strict about only using the lite subset of Protobuf OR
2. Delete the `implementation ... protobuf-lite` line and have ProGuard strip out the classes that you don't need